# Calling class using service in Form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I have a question about service and Form in Symfony2,so I created my calss form and I hope to add a multiselect list of cities then I want to get list of cities from another class "city",so how I can call my class "city" in my form using "Service" to get a function "getcities" to return me a list of cities? (I dont use Doctrine here)...

**Edit**

```
 namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CityType extends AbstractType
{ 
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'choices' => array( /**
                     * Here I will call function getcities(return list of cities)
                      */

        )
    ));
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'choice';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'gender';
}
}
```

class City.php :

```
Class City {

  /**
   * here i will get list of cities 
   */


  public function getcities()
  {
     .....
    return $Listcities;
  }

  }
```

So I would like to use "Service" to call function "getcities" in form?

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far?

Comment: You can see my edit in my first message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form objects are not container-aware...at least, they're not meant to be. That said, your controller should use the service to get the cities, and then it should pass that list into the form object either through a constructor or a method.

Controller:

```
class SomethingController
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        ...
        $cities = $this->get("citiesService")->getCities();
        $form = $this->createForm(new SomeType($cities), $someEntity);
        ...
    }
}
```

Form:

```
class SomeType extends AbstractType
{
    private $cities;

    public function __construct($cities)
    {
        $this->cities = $cities;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Now you have access to $this->cities, so you can use it to build the form
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok great i understand but it's the only way to call functions using service,because I will use this form in a few other forms when I will need list of cities?

Comment: and how i call my function in multiselect list in my form?

Comment: Yes: you would need to implement this for each form that requires a list of cities. To implement multi-select, you'd follow the documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Specifically, you'd use the type `choice`, and you'd make sure that the `multiple` option was set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can set City object as form data object?

so it can looks like that...

`$form = $this->createForm(new SomeType(), new City());`

```
class SomeType extends AbstractType
{ 
    public buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormsEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formFactory) {
                $event->getForm()->add(
                    $formFactory->createNamed(
                        'gender',
                        'choice',
                        null,
                        array(
                            'choices' => $event->getData()->getCites()
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```